# Use of curl Paypal API in php

Tags: php, curl

How to use the curl function in php for implementing paypal

The curl code is below

> curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
>
> -H "Accept: application/json" \
>
> -u "AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd:EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX" \
>
> -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

How to implement in php with curl ?

Please help

Comment: Sorry, you can't replace one question with a totally different one. Together with the answer below this is now a collective work and you can't just vandalise that work by replacing half of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check it out @ [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Second, you will have to use setopt for the -H, -u, -d options.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");

//Here you will have to add your options, I think this code will bring you far :-)
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```